# PHP - Passing PHP functions within TWIG templates

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can pass PHP code directly within the templates in TWIG without having to create separate extensions for each function. Basically a simple function that could parse out the PHP and run the code in the template.

Example:

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('php_parse_function', function () {
     //parse php code here
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Use-case Example:

```
{{ php_parse_function | php code }}
```

The problem with doing something like this is that I would have to include an entire code-block in a string, which is to print html encapsulated in another string, which will have class/other-attributes in another layer of quotes.

Example:

```
{{php_parse_function | "echo '<section class=\'Yo\' id=\'2\'>'</section>" }}
```

So is there a workaround for something like this?

Comment: Twig is meant to not allow this. And it isn't really hard to do, is it? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Comment: @Sven updated it to explain a bit more

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** (after question edit)

No, It's not possible to execute php code directly from Twig. You can create filters or functions and pass strings as arg.

How? This way (orginal answer):

---

Anywhere inside the controller you're loading Twig:

```
// ...
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, $params); // load Twig env
$tsf = new Twig_SimpleFunction('fooTwig', function ($str) {
    return eval($str);
});
$twig->addFunction($tsf);
// ...
```

**Then:**

```
{{ fooTwig('echo "Hello, World! What kind of sorcery is this? F in hex is "; echo hexdec("F");') }}
```

---

And remember you can use filters too!

**Controller:**

```
// ...
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, $params); // load Twig env
$tsf = new Twig_SimpleFilter('fooTwig', function ($str, $fn) {
    $args = array_merge(array($str), array_slice(func_get_args(), 2));
    return call_user_func_array($fn, $args);
});
$twig->addFilter($tsf);
// ...
```

**Then:**

```
{{ 'F'|fooTwig('hexdec') }}
```

If you are using Symfony2 or any other framework, is the same logic. You should just investigate where to add the Twig simple function/filter.

Comment: The problem with this is that if I try to use something like {{ fooTwig(<div class="ONE"></div> }} it won't read the location of the class because it can't parse the quotes.

Comment: Why are you sending a div to php??? Btw this totally works: `{{ fooTwig('echo \'<div class="ONE"></div>\';') }}`

Comment: @viarnes I understand that I can do it like that but that's adding another lay of quotes which is what I'm trying to avoid doing. I want the code to be parsed as normal without have to encapsulate it.

Comment: Ok. No, that's not possible. Why are you sending html to php? I'm sure there must be a workaround for your problem.